# Which Event to use to capture changes in a control's state before the form closes though pressing the Enter button? VB6!

Tags: vb6

I want to store the changed value of the ListIndex of a ComboBox when the user selects a value from it. I tried using the _Change or the _LostFocus events, but those are not triggered when the Close button of the form has its Default property set to true and the user presses enter!

Is there a way around this?

Comment: And you cannot do that in the `Close` button event handler because?..

Comment: @GSerg: I suppose I can, I am from a WPF background, so are used to bind properties of controls directly to a class. Changing a property of a control might affect the state of the class and I want other controls on the form to reflect that. I prefer the logic for that to be hidden in the class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pressing `Enter` to fire a default command button certainly doesn't raise `LostFocus` events. That's a classic VB6 gotcha!

Have you tried the `Click` event of the ComboBox? The `Change` event is raised if the user *types* in a ComboBox, but it isn't if they select from the drop-down list. The ComboBox events are a sort of weird combination of TextBox events and ListBox events.

You may need to add something to the `Click` event of the command button. Alternatively you could add something to the `Form_Unload` event. You could even set the focus to the command button in the `Click` event of the command button, to deliberately raise any LostFocus events.

Comment: The Click eventhandler it was!